# How to reboot into ubuntu from Microsoft Windows without manually selecting the grub entry?

Tags: boot, grub2

This is the reverse question of [How to reboot into Windows from Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18170/how-to-reboot-into-windows-from-ubuntu).

I'm using a PC with Windows/Ubuntu dual system. The PC is shared with others, so the default boot system in Grub is set to Windows, and the timeout is 1 second.

In order to switch the running Windows to Ubuntu, I have to reboot the windows and wait at the very short time of grub menu to choose the ubuntu entry. Many times I had missed or forgotten the chance and the system booted to windows again. (so I have to reboot again). Is there a way to directly reboot the windows to Ubuntu? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you raise the grub timeout also!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I choose which OS grub will reboot me into—before I reboot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/63065/how-can-i-choose-which-os-grub-will-reboot-me-intobefore-i-reboot)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at: [How can I choose which OS grub will reboot me into—before I reboot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63065/how-can-i-choose-which-os-grub-will-reboot-me-intobefore-i-reboot)

This looks excactly like what you want. Basically it proposes to use grub-reboot.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But the answers to that question were all assuming that the OS before rebooting was Linux, which is different from my case: Windows. I've modified the title to be more clear.

Comment: ok, well that was not clear to me. sorry. I don't know how grub-reboot works, but I'd suggest you look into that. You propably have to use an ext* driver for windows in order to mount your boot partition, so you can edit grub and imitate grub-reboot behaviour.

Comment: unfortunately this does not answer the question